# Oracle 19c - Zero padded year

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have some zero padded year DATE column values (e.g. 0018-04-30), but not all values.  Most are 4 digit years (e.g. 2022).  What's the most efficient way of converting to a year with century (i.e. 2018-04-30).

I'm not a Oracle guy, but what I came up with is to use a `CASE` statement with `EXTRACT` and `ADD_MONTHS` functions:

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DateColumn) < 1000 THEN ADD_MONTHS(DateColumn,(12*2000)) 
    ELSE DateColumn 
END
```

Example:

```sql
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(
        CASE 
            WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (DATE '18-04-30')) < 1000 THEN ADD_MONTHS((DATE '18-04-30'),(12*2000)) 
            ELSE (DATE '18-04-30') 
        END,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS CorrectedDate
FROM DUAL ;
```

Is there a better, more efficient, way of doing this?

Comment: Your question is how to add two thousand years to all dates where the year < 100?

Comment: The solution you found is probably the cleanest and most efficient. But there is a better solution: if you know for sure that all dates should have been 20XX and not 00XX, then fix the data in the table itself, once and for all. Then you won't have to remember to do it in every query you write against that table. Aside from that though: is adding 2000 what you really need, in all cases? Can you have dates in year 0096, which were meant to be 1996, not 2096?

Comment: [this link](https://www.foxinfotech.in/2019/06/oracle-database-convert-dates-to-before-2000-for-years-50-99-and-to-2000-and-later-for-years-00-49.html) might help I think

Answer (score 1):

You may remove leading zeroes from the date using `ltrim` function  and use [`RR` date format element](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-6C75461E-2E18-4C35-9EB4-038A7E1C9C1F) to convert the result to a date, which was introduced for y2k problem (I presume this is the source of such dates):

> ```
> with dates(dt) as (
>   select *
>   from sys.odcidatelist(
>     date '0018-04-30',
>     date '3018-05-30',
>     date '0070-12-29'
>   )
> )
> select
>   to_date(
>     ltrim(to_char(dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), '0'),
>     'rr-mm-dd'
>   ) as dt
> from dates;
> ```
>
> ```
> | DT         |
> | :--------- |
> | 2018-04-30 |
> | 3018-05-30 |
> | 1970-12-29 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1a7f31656cc0d5ce93556c878533e311)*

Comment: 0070-12-29 got converted to 1970-12-29 , how?

Comment: @DontDownvote because this format element is specifically designed for abbreviated dates near the year 2000, where the first two digits depend on the current year compared to the 50'th year of the current century. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-6C75461E-2E18-4C35-9EB4-038A7E1C9C1F

Comment: This does not use a `DATE` data-type in the example input (it uses strings) and will fail with most default date formats [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2c25ab6d3f3b15a897a5c0c5e98ec3d4)

Comment: The OP stated the data type of his column is `date`, and from everything he said and showed, we should trust him. The inputs are not strings. This is what MT0 said, I just wanted to express my view that there's nothing in the original post to suggest otherwise. To me this solution is not helpful; one of the downvotes is from me.

Comment: @MT0 Thank you very much, it was my mistake. I've updated the answer to turn dates to strings first

Comment: Changed the answer to convert from date to string first - why would one need to do that? What the OP is doing already is much cleaner than converting to string and working with strings. My vote remains.

Comment: @mathguy Because I've added this statement to my answer: *... which was introduced for y2k problem (I presume this is the source of such dates)*. I still presume that this dates were generated by invalid conversion of real dates to strings and then back again. This may be validated only if we check the date for some old data (for which we absolutely sure it is from 20'th century), but data semantics is out of scope of the question. Then the `case` expression should be more complex. Though, this answer will work only for the nearest 27 years

Comment: @mathguy As I see now, your comment to the question also contains the possibility of such a case

Answer (score 1):

Use an INTERVAL literal to add 2000 years to your dates:

```
SELECT dt + INTERVAL '2000' YEAR(4)
  FROM DATE_TABLE
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=11269e78cf5bdd5fab4e4a698ba55778)

Also, your CASE expression can be a bit simpler:

```
CASE 
  WHEN DateColumn < DATE '1000-01-01' THEN DateColumn + INTERVAL '2000' YEAR(4)
  ELSE DateColumn 
END
```

Comment: Adding an interval will work, but only due to a coincidence - 2000 is divisible by 400. ADD_MONTHS works correctly with things like Feb. 29 (which does not exist in non-leap years); adding an interval of years does not, we just need to be lucky. Adding multiples of 400 years is ok, because that (and **only** that) maps all leap years to leap years and all non-leap years to non-leap years.